# Check if string starts with in array values

Tags: php

I have an array of excluded category IDs. I'm trying to fetch data from the DB and filter products based on this array.

- **1000** is an example of **Category Level 1** ID
- **1000001** is an example of **Category Level 2** ID
- **1000001021** is an example of **Category Level 3** ID

So if level 1 is excluded, products of level 2 and 3 are automatically excluded. Currently I'm doing this:

```
$excludedCategories = ['1000', '100011'];

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $category = "1". $row['category'] . $row['sub_category'] . $row['category_id'];
    foreach ($excludeCategories as $exCategory) {
        if( substr($category, 0, strlen($exCategory)) === $exCategory ) {
            echo 'Category'. $category . " matches " . $exCategory . "<br>";
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

.. but is there a better way of doing it without running the second loop?

Comment: may in `in_array($category, $excludedCategories)`?

Comment: preg_match can be used to solve it pretty easy if the array values can be converted to  regex pattern if not

Comment: @manix Probably not because i need to check IDs that "start with"

Comment: I see. You are right

Comment: @3zzy Why do you need to loop the excludedCategories if the first start with 1000? I guess the second is automatically excluded, Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Its just an example, 1000 is just one of the IDs, there're 1001, 1010 etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you implode `$excludedCategories` to make a pattern for `preg_match`, you don't need the loop.

```
$excludedCategories = ['1000', '100011'];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $category = "1". $row['category'] . $row['sub_category'] . $row['category_id'];
        if( preg_match("/^".implode("|",$excludedCategories)."/", $category)) {
            echo "Category: $category Excluded <br>";
     }
}
```

Comment: In this case it is not a concern, but consider using [preg_quote](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) on all items of the array.